# Improve performance of reversing array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve question at [Reverse Game](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reverse-game)
When I submit my code, in some of the testcases it is getting timeout.
I think problem may be in reverseSubArray() method but I am not sure how to improve performance here.
Following is my code:

```
    public class ReverseGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    int[] numberOFBalls = new int[testCases];
    int[] ballNumberArray = new int[testCases];

    for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
    {
        numberOFBalls[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        ballNumberArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
    {
        process(numberOFBalls[i], ballNumberArray[i]);
    }
    scanner.close();
    }

    private static void process(int totalNumberOFBalls, int ballNumber)
    {
    int[] ballsArray = new int[totalNumberOFBalls];
    int maximumNumberOnBall = totalNumberOFBalls - 1; // This is because
                              // balls are numbered
                              // from 0.
    // As the first step is to reverse the Balls arrangement, So insert into
    // ballsArray in descending order of index.
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOFBalls; i++)
        ballsArray[i] = maximumNumberOnBall--;

    for (int i = 1; i < totalNumberOFBalls; i++)
    {
        ballsArray = reverseSubArray(ballsArray, i);
    }

    int position = findPosition(ballsArray, ballNumber);
    System.out.println(position);
    }

    private static int[] reverseSubArray(int[] a, int fromIndex)
    {
    int temp = 0, counter = 1;
    int midIndex = (a.length - fromIndex) / 2;
    for (int i = fromIndex; i < fromIndex + midIndex; i++)
    {
        temp = a[a.length - (counter)];
        a[a.length - (counter)] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
        counter++;
    }

    /*
     * System.out.println(); for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
     * System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
     */
    return a;
    }


    private static int findPosition(int[] ballsArray, int ballNumber)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < ballsArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (ballsArray[i] == ballNumber)
        return i;
    }
    return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review; this may be better asked at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  I'd flag this for mod attention and request it be moved before I repost it over there, though.

Comment: Actually it's a good question for Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of your solution is `O(n ^ 2)`. It is too slow for `n = 10 ^ 5`. So you need to use a better algorithm. Here is simple linear solution which uses the fact that we do not need to know the positions of all balls(we need only the `k`-th):

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int testsCount = in.nextInt();
        for (int t = 0; t < testsCount; t++) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int k = in.nextInt();
            // Simulates all rotations,
            // but keeps track only of the k-th ball.
            // It does not matter what happens to the others.
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                if (k >= i)
                    k = i + n - 1 - k;
            out.println(k);
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

This solution has an `O(n)` time complexity and easily passes all test cases.
It is actually possible to find the positions of all balls in linear time, but it is not required here.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. But unfortunately I didn't understood it well. Can I request you to provide me some explanation or algo or links which could help me.